# Intermittent StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, tdd

Working on TDD for Python, chapter 5, Django 1.8, Python 2.7 and after the introduction of CSRF tokens, things get weird.  I've read plenty of other posts and been able to work past most issues however I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this one...

I keep getting a StaleReferenceException but I can't reproduce.  It comes up intermittently.  If I run the functional_test.py twice or three times in succession the test will finally comes back as expected...

I'm not sure if this is a timing issue or something else.  Any ideas on how to track this down?

```
(venv_unittesting) roadblock:superlists Admin$ python functional_test.py 
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_open_home_page_header_input_table (__main__.NewVisitorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_test.py", line 39, in test_open_home_page_header_input_table
    rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
  File "/Users/Admin/coding/django/venv_unittesting/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 320, in find_elements_by_tag_name
    return self.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name)
  File "/Users/Admin/coding/django/venv_unittesting/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 680, in find_elements
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "/Users/Admin/coding/django/venv_unittesting/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/Admin/coding/django/venv_unittesting/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/Admin/coding/django/venv_unittesting/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <table id="id_list_table"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 9.359s

FAILED (errors=1)
(venv_unittesting) roadblock:superlists Admin$ python functional_test.py 
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_open_home_page_header_input_table (__main__.NewVisitorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_test.py", line 43, in test_open_home_page_header_input_table
    table.text,)
AssertionError: Not located on this page:
Buy Peacock Feathers

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 8.907s

FAILED (failures=1)
(venv_unittesting) roadblock:superlists Admin$
```

Functional_test.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest

import time


class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(2)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()
        # self.fail('Finish Testing! or put next task here')



    #A new user heard about a Todo list and want to to
    # Open the add

    def test_open_home_page_header_input_table(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

        self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)
        header_text = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').text
        self.assertIn('To-Do', header_text)
        inputbox = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_new_item')
        self.assertEqual(inputbox.get_attribute('placeholder'),
                        'Enter a to-do item')

        inputbox.send_keys('Buy peacock Feathers')
        inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        # time.sleep(10)

        table = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_list_table')
        rows = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tr')
        # self.assertTrue(
        #   any(row == '1: Buy Peacock Feathers' for row in rows),
        #       'Not located on this page')
        self.assertIn('1: Buy peacock feathers', [row.text for row in rows])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugh...the book was TLDR!

Page 389

```
Unexpected StaleElementException errors from Selenium often mean you have some kind of race condition. You should probably specify an explicit interaction/wait pattern.
```

And it's fixed...